# .htaccess redirect to subdomain and hide in uri?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect every request for:

`http://example.com/page1.php (<-non-existent url to file)`

to

`http://example.com/content/sites/page1.php (<-real path to file in folder structure)`

while still continuing to show:

`http://example.com/page1.php`

in the browser and using a .htaccess file located in root folder.

Is this possible in any way? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: paste what you did in htaccess

Comment: @MohammedElhag so far i have just code for file extensions:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how URL rewriting works. You should consider a router (sending everything to index.php and dispatch from there)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz my initial thought was to redirect each and every non-existent url (generated by history.pushstate())to index.php, content is loaded via ajax

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is how big frameworks do it: everything not physically existent (reachable from the net) is routed through index.php

Comment: @LarsStegelitz so, if im understand it right, htaccess would do just the redirect to index.php part, next i need to build a basic server side routing system in php...?

Comment: Correct. The main problem with a htaccess based solution is, that with every new schema you want to add, you'd have to extend the htaccess rule. A PHP router is much more flexible...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz found smth like this in medium https://medium.com/the-andela-way/how-to-build-a-basic-server-side-routing-system-in-php-e52e613cf241

Comment: Yo, looks good to me... give it a try :)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz will start from bare-bones https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/ and then add up whats needed, thanksfor help

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment ,The folwoing rules are what you did:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

And they do checking whether the request is not directory and then check if it is accept `.php` then rewrite it and no need for that at all .

Try only this , in general:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+\.php)$   content/sites/$1 [L]
```

If you want it only for `page1.php` do this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(page1\.php)$  content/sites/$1 [L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test`